# ¿Como quitar el focus 'resaltado' del autocompletado en visual code?

Tags: vscode, visual

sucede que cada ves que escribo un trozo de código autocompletado este viene sombreado  y si uno quiere escribir por ejemplo un variable tiene que escribirla completa por que no aparecen las sugerencias a menos que quites el foco moviendo el puntero hacia otro lado y volviendo al mismo lugar,esto es muy incómodo a veces por quieres que te detecte la variable  tan solo escribiendo la primera letra y no tener que escribirlo todo, en atom esto no sucede,espero puedan ayudarme,gracias
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Yo solamente coloco `Esc` para escribir con autocompletado despues de crear el if, pero por lo que quieres se debe reconfigurar eso

Comment: veo que presionar __esc__ no ayuda mucho , ya que el tecto que viene por defecto no se borra. :/ ,  no solo sucede con if si con varios trozos de código , si supongo que en las configraciones se editará pero no se cual es

Answer (score 0):

Puedes volver a cargar las sugerencias usando la combinacion de teclas:

> Ctrl + Espacio